# all of proper subset of ${a_1,...,a_n}$ is not relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

we know prior that $[a_1,...,a_n](\frac{p}{a_1},...,\frac{p}{a_n})=|a_1...a_n|$
that $p=a_1...a_n$,$a_i \in \Bbb N$  now

how to prove $\forall n\in \Bbb N , n\ge 2$ exist $n$ number as $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)=1$ but all of proper subset of ${a_1,...,a_n}$ is not relatively prime.

for example: $\gcd(6,10,15)=1$ but $\gcd(10,15) \not = 1$,$\gcd(10,6) \not = 1$,$\gcd(6,15) \not = 1 $

Comment: Your 'statement' quantifies the same variable twice with different quantifiers: $(\forall n\in \Bbb N_{>2})(\exists n)\ldots$ There's something wrong.

Comment: @GitGud: It’s okay: the existential quantifier applies to $a_1,\dots,a_n$. $\forall n\ge 2\exists a_1,\dots,a_n$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't get it. Is $(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(\exists n\in \Bbb N)\bigl(P(n)\bigr)$ a statement?

Comment: @GitGud: You’re not reading it correctly. It’s not $(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(\exists n\in\Bbb N)\big(P(n)\big)$; it’s $$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\Big(n\ge 2\to\exists a_1,\dots,a_n\in\Bbb Z^+\big(P(n)\big)\Big)\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. The singular *number* mislead me completly.

Comment: @GitGud: Understandably: the English is a little awkward. As you’ve probably figured out, ‘exist $n$ number as ...’ is to be read as ‘there exist $n$ numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $p_1,\dots,p_n$ be distinct prime numbers. What happens if you look at products of $n-1$ of these primes? In your example, for instance, you’re looking at $2\cdot3$, $2\cdot5$, and $3\cdot5$.

Comment: it's true for $n-1$ element subset .for $i$ element ?($i=2,...,n-2$) how to work?

Comment: @agustin: You don’t need to look at any other size subset: $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ has $n$ subsets of size $n-1$, which you can use to construct $a_1,\dots,a_n$.